# Mysql Full search from 2 columns in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have 2 tables. One is questions and the other is answers with the following format.

> question(id,text,user)
>
> answer(id,text,question_id,user)

both tables have the same number of rows obviously.

when a user searches for a phrase or a word I want it to search in both question text and answer text for that word and return the matches by most common.

I tried using the Full search of mySQL but I couldn't make it work on 2 different tables and 2 columns.

I also don't want to merge the question and answer into another table if possible.

Question table :

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `text` text NOT NULL,
 `answer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `user` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


ALTER TABLE `questions`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `questions` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`);



ALTER TABLE `questions`
 MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answers table :

```
 CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `question` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


 ALTER TABLE `answers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
 ALTER TABLE `answers` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`);


ALTER TABLE `answers`
 MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Please show us some sample data.

Comment: Do you mean data from the tables  ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: please show us configuration setting for your column `text` and `question` in MySQL

Comment: I am not sure how to send a picture here but there

Question  : http://prntscr.com/jx0h0g

Answer : http://prntscr.com/jx0h3p

Both text fields are indexed

Comment: What I tried was this 
`SELECT count(*) from questions,answers where answers.question=questions.id and
match(questions.text,answers.text) against ('hello' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
`
obviously it gave me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query on multiple keywords, an advice would be to store it somewhere in your application code (i.e use an explode function to separate each keyword).

Also in app code, try to generate your WHERE statement dynamically (since you cannot know in advance the number of keywords to be used):

```
String sql_where = " ";
for(int i = 0, i<search.length, i++){
   if (i=0)
      sql_where += "WHERE TEXT LIKE '%"+search[i]+"%';
   else
sql_where += "\n OR TEXT LIKE '%"+search[i]+"%';
}
```

You will then need to query both your tables by using:

```
query = "SELECT ID,TEXT,'QUE' AS TYPE FROM QUESTION "+sql_where+" UNION SELECT ID,TEXT,'ANS' AS TYPE FROM ANSWER "+sql_where+";";
```

Note that type was added to each in order to separate the source of result row. This will help you in case you need to display the location the result was extracted from.

For the rest, I'll just explain the general idea. You will want to use the search array built earlier to compare to your result set. For each word, try to look for it in each returned row. On the side, you will create an array to store the common hits and the array index (Which will be used later). When you find a word in a row, its corresponding entry in your count array will be incremented by 1.

After you're done, all you have to is reorder the count array based on the descending order of hits. You will notice that the index id created earlier will shift, which will allow you to use it in the following stage.

For loading, you will loop on the count array, and load the result entry from result set using the index column created in the count array.

Assume the above code as a general idea, since I don't know which language you're working with

Answer (score 0):

```
"(select id,text, 'que' as type from question WHERE text LIKE '%keyword%')
UNION
(select id,text,'ans' as type from answer WHERE text LIKE '%keyword%')";
```

if you have confusion that the row is selected from which table, you can check type for that.